# Variables and preg_match PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am creating an app that displays only pictures where a certain profilename as been appended on to the beginning of the text.

for example 3 files in the folder are : Rogue-fastcar.jpg , John-girls.png, Petra-moneyNmore.jpg

I would like to return only the picture that has the profile that is stored within the session. So far its showing pictures from all users.

Thanks for the assistance, much appreciated.

```
foreach ($images as $index => $image) {
    $extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image)));
    $subject = $image;
    $profile = "$_SESSION["profile"]";
    $pattern = '/.$profile./';

    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);



    if ($matches) {
        echo "Worse Behavior";
        if(!in_array($extension, $extensions)){
            unset($images[$index]);
        }else{
            $images[$index] = array(
                'full' => $this->path. '/' . $image,
                'thum' => $this->path. '/thumb/' . $image               
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($_SESSION['profile'], '/') . '/';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dots in your $pattern = '/.$profile./'; should be matching to any character that is not a newline. You probably want to try something like this:

$pattern= '/^$profile[-]{1}.*/' This should say you want to match anything that starts with the profile name, one dash, and then followed by anything else. (. is anything except the /n character and * is 0 or more of the previous pattern) Hope this helps.

Comment: no it didnt work but ill continue working on it until something happens. Thanks again

Comment: oops, I forgot that you can't put '' s around a variable in php. it makes it a string instead of a variable. try $pattern= '/^'.$profile.'[-]{1}.*/'; I tried this with the following test code and it worked: <?php
$profile = 'Rogue';
echo $profile.'<br>';
$pattern= '/^'.$profile.'[-]{1}.*/';
echo $pattern.'<br>';
if(preg_match("$pattern", "Rogue-fastcar.jpg")){
 
 echo "yay";
}
else{
 echo "no joy";
}

Comment: Thank you :D If you like it, would you accept mine as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you were having a few issues escaping quotes and concatenating strings.

It also looks like you're going a bit of a roundabout way to do what you'd like.

What we could do is:

```
// Get length of $_SESSION['profile']
$profileLength = strlen($_SESSION['profile']);

// Get that amount of characters from the image name starting at the first character
$imagePrefix = substr($image, 0, $profileLength);

// Compare the first X characters of image names to $_SESSION['profile']
if($imagePrefix == $_SESSION['profile']){..}

// Put it together now:
foreach ($images as $index => $image) {
    $extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image)));
    // $subject = $image;
    // $profile = "$_SESSION["profile"]"; 
    // $pattern = '/.$profile./';
    // preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

    // if ($matches) {

    $profileLength = strlen($_SESSION['profile']);
    $imagePrefix = substr($image, 0, $profileLength);

    if($imagePrefix == $_SESSION['profile']){
        echo "Worse Behavior";

        if(!in_array($extension, $extensions)){
            unset($images[$index]);
        }else{
            $images[$index] = array(
                'full' => $this->path. '/' . $image,
                'thum' => $this->path. '/thumb/' . $image
            );
        }
    }
}
```

However, to address the reasons why it didn't work in the first place:

```
foreach ($images as $index => $image) {
    $extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image)));
    $subject = $image;

    // This should not be quoted
    // $profile = "$_SESSION["profile"]"; 
    $profile = $_SESSION["profile"]; 

    // The concatenation here is close, but you forgot some single quotes
    // $pattern = '/.$profile./';
    $pattern = '/'.$profile.'/';

    // Not only that, but you can combine the two lines into:
    $pattern = '/' . $_SESSION['profile'] . '/';

    // Furthermore, when putting anything into a regular expression, you should sanitize:
    $pattern = '/' . preg_quote($_SESSION['profile']) . '/';

    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

    // $matches may be interpreted as true or false depending on array length. Try instead..
    // if ($matches) {
    if (count($matches) > 0) {
        echo "Worse Behavior";
        if(!in_array($extension, $extensions)){
            unset($images[$index]);
        }else{
            $images[$index] = array(
                'full' => $this->path. '/' . $image,
                'thum' => $this->path. '/thumb/' . $image               
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i see what u did there. trying to make it work for hours n you did it in seconds lol. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are at least two problems in your PHP code: first of all this is a syntax error:

```
$profile = "$_SESSION["profile"]";
```

try with this:

```
$profile = $_SESSION["profile"];
```

then your regex is wrong, because `.` matches any character, but it matches just one. Thus you need to use `*` instead which matches any character and any multiplicity too.

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out that there are smarter ways (and more readable) to get a file's extension

```
$extension = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get image from folder with profile name

```
$pathToImagesFolder = "/images/"; // path to your images folder
//
$profileName = $_SESSION["profile"];
// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($pathToImagesFolder)){
  if ($dh = opendir($pathToImagesFolder)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
        if($file != '..' && $file != '.') {
                $fileDetails = explode('.',$file);
                if(is_array($fileDetails) && $fileDetails[0] == $profileName) {
                        echo $file; //Image with extension
                        //Your Code
                }
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```